# Animate View Visibility Pushing down Views Below

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-constraintlayout

I am currently implementing a fairly simple login screen using a custom implementation of material's *TextInputLayout*. I am using a custom view to show field errors. The problem here is that when I set the view from GONE to VISIBLE, it moves the fields above and under it. I only want the views below to move down, and keep the views above in the same position.

I have tried using the *ViewPropertyAnimator* but this just animates the fading in and out of the error view.

```
errorView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        errorView.animate()
            .alpha(1f)
            .setListener(null)
            .duration = 300
```

```
errorView.animate()
            .alpha(0.0f)
            .setDuration(300)
            .setListener(object : AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator) {
                    super.onAnimationEnd(animation)
                    errorView.visibility = View.GONE
                }
            })
```

In essence I would like the following to happen instead:

```
---------------------
| Email             |
---------------------  
                     <- Error to show here and move password field down
---------------------  |
| Password          |  v
---------------------


Result:
---------------------
| Email             |  <- Stay in same position
---------------------
----------------------
|Email must be valid | <- Error
----------------------

---------------------  |
| Password          |  v
---------------------
```

Below is an example of an XML layout to exemplify this. Note that this does not match my layout but still shows the same problem.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/errorView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:text="Email must be valid"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/login"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:text="Login"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try objectanimator and change the y axis of your password view

Comment: you can use android:animateLayoutChanges="true" to your root layout

Comment: Hey, I think you can fix this issue in your xml. Can you please share your xml code?

Comment: I have edited the question to explain my use case better. @Maitri I have tried that approach but that does not seem to work. The views around the error view still move either up or down depending on their position.

Comment: @AkanshiSrivastava I have added an XML layout to exemplify my usecase. Please note that it is not my actual layout, but behaves the same.

Comment: @PembaTamang I tried your approach, however, the error view still moves the email field up even after moving the password field down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my use case, all the child views are centred in a parent, thus making this impossible to achieve, because the parent pushes the child views (both up and down) in order to both *create space for the error view*, *while keeping all the views **centred***.

The approach I chose instead is to specify a top margin to the *email field*, instead of centring the child views in the parent view.

This way, when the parent adds the *error* view - after visibility changes - it only pushes down all the views under the *email* field as intended.

Answer (score 3):

Use XML Tag `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` on parent layout.